# File attribute flags is controlled by code or OS?

Tags: c#, file-attributes

I am learning about the file attribute enum and have a two questions which I can't find a concrete answer to (although I have my own opinion).

My application checks to see if the Archive flag has been set or not. During my testing, I create a .txt file on my desktop, and removed the flag to archive. I then opened the file, added a line of text and saved the file. The attribute Archive was re-set. This is logical and desirable.

My first question is, what is setting the flag, the program or the OS?

My second question is, should I ever be setting the flags or for the most part can I rely on the OS (assuming that the OS is the thing which sets the flags).

Comment: How are you editing the file?  It's not clear (although it might be implied, I don't know) whether your application is editing the file...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @AndrasZoltan in this case, just opening the file in question (double clicking), adding text, then file save and exit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the archive file attribute flag using the `ATTRIB` command line or the underlying Windows API (e.g. allowing "your code" full control of the flag). However, when a file is modified the archive flag is set. That is not something you have to do in your application or code. The expected usage scenario is this:

- The operating system will set the flag when a file is created or modified
- The backup application (e.g. "your code") will reset the flag when a file has been backed up

However, relying on the archive flag for backup can be problematic because multiple independent backup applications may be using the flag.

Comment: Yes, I agree that other programs may set it but I'm hoping if a home machine has only 1 copy it will be fine. Or, even better, I'd let the user choose (either by flag, file size or by M5a hash). Thank you.

Comment: @PaulZahra: No, any decent backup application will not rely on the archive flag. However, in the context of this question (who is responsible for setting and clearing the flag?) it is the "backup application" that clears the flag.

Answer (score 1):

If the file has been 'touched' since the last backup DOS sets this archive bit.

e.g. when a file with a clear archive bit is moved from one place on a file system to another, the archive bit reverts to being set.

Comment: DOS as in the operating system that manages the disk, e.g. Unix, Windows

Comment: A little bizarre to use the word "DOS" to refer to Unix.

Comment: In a general sense DOS refers to just about any operating system, while i admit it is more commonly used to refer to MS-DOS, it is nonetheless valid and in so much, not in any way bizarre ;)

Comment: I don't recall having ever heard the term "DOS" used to refer to anything other than MS-DOS, PC-DOS, or DOS/360. The general abbreviation for "Operating System" is "OS", which you have used yourself.

Comment: Indeed, mostly it is used to refer to MS-DOS and it's 'like minded' OS' although it is also used as a reference to any operating system... See http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/DOS.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_operating_system